# Suddenly the moving/scaling arrows of the Unity 2D UI looks faded and the grid is gone

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a 2D game in Unity, and suddenly I noticed that the moving arrows are looking faded (as shown in the uploaded picture). I have no idea what I did to cause this. Can anyone help me? Thanks ahead.[image: Picture that shows the problem quite clear]

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the grid is gone:
Use this Toggle in the scene view to enable the grid.[image: Toggle Grid]

Regarding the transform gizmo being smaller and faded: try restarting unity, resetting layout. What version of Unity are you using? Are you using any editor-enhancing assets? Are you running Unity on a Mac? Maybe write unity a support ticket.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
The issue with the arrows was related to the Z position of the objects, so I consider it resolved at this point. Thanks for the help with the grid!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this because I had the same issue. I ended up resolving it by switching to 3d view, then rotating so I was behind the 2d camera, and switching back to 2d view. Hope this helps anyone else who encounters this issue.